# Add space using str replace for pandas series

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I must be misunderstanding how to use replace.

input

```
          box
0      11M000
1  11M000(MU)
```

desired output

```
          box
0      11M000
1  11M000 (MU)
```

code

```
import pandas as pd
data={'box':['11M000','11M000(MU)']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['box'] = df['box'].str.replace('.(MU)'," (MU)", regex=True)
```

what I'm getting now

```
0          11M000
1    11M000 (MU))
```

Comment: `df['box'] = df['box'].str.replace('.(MU.)'," (MU)")`

Answer (score 1):

```
df['box'] = df['box'].str.replace('('," (")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the first brace

```
df['box'].str.replace('(', ' (')
0         11M000
1    11M000 (MU)
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape `()` in regex because special characters and replace with back reference by `\\1`, `regex=True` is default in [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html), so should be omited:

```
data={'box':['11M000','11M000(MU)']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['box'] = df['box'].str.replace('(\(MU\))'," \\1")
print (df)
           box
0       11M000
1  11M000 (MU)
```

No regex solution with `regex=False` parameter and no escape `()`:

```
df['box'] = df['box'].str.replace('(MU)'," (MU)", regex=False)
print (df)
           box
0       11M000
1  11M000 (MU)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using regex and the () are special characters. You'll have to escape it since you want to match on the character instead of using the special usecase in regex context.

```
import pandas as pd
data={'box':['11M000','11M000(MU)']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['box'] = df['box'].str.replace(".\(MU", " (MU", regex=True)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

`regex=True` means the first pattern is a regex. In regexes, parentheses are part of the syntax.

Meaning `.(MU)` as regex matches exactly what `.MU` regex matches (parentheses are used for grouping and you don't repeat your group or anything like that, so they do nothing here). So it picks up `(MU` (dot matching `(`) from `11M000 (MU)`, without the closing one.

If you want to fix this, simply change `regex=True` to `regex=False` - regexes are slow, they're used to find patterns, and you're just finding a normal substring.